# Recursive call for SPListItem Update method when called from a event receiver ItemUpdated

Tags: event-receivers, sharepoint-server, itemupdated

I have fallen in a serious problem about the `SPListItem` Update method. When I make a event receiver to intercept `SPListItem` change or update with `SPItemEventReceiver ItemUpdated method`, the event is recursively called.

source:

```
  public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
    base.ItemUpdated(properties);

    SPList list = properties.List;

    SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;

    if ("Oui" == properties.ListItem["Envoyé vers le Directeur"].ToString())
    {
        SPListItem copyItem = item;

        MoveItemsToFolder(properties, list, "Dossiers envoyés Rédaction", copyItem);

        item["Service"] = "direction";
        item.Update();

        string[] cols = { "Envoyé vers le Directeur", "Archivé" };
        HideColumns(list, cols);

    }
    else if ("Oui" == properties.ListItem["Validé par le Directeur"].ToString())
    {

        SPListItem copyItem = item;

        MoveItemsToFolder(properties, list, "Direction", copyItem);

        item["Service"] = "bureauOrdre";
        item.Update();

        string[] cols = { "Validé par le Directeur", "Envoyé vers le Directeur" };
        HideColumns(list, cols);
    }
    else if ("Oui" == properties.ListItem["Archivé"].ToString())
    {

        SPListItem copyItem = item;

        MoveItemsToFolder(properties, list, "Archives", copyItem);

        item["Service"] = "Archive";
        item.Update();

        string[] cols = { "Validé par le Directeur", "Envoyé vers le Directeur" };
        HideColumns(list, cols);
    }
    else
    {

        item["Service"] = "redaction";
        item.Update();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use `SPItemEventReceiver.EnableEventFiring` [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceiverbase.eventfiringenabled%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

You can do

```
var eventRecTemp = new SPItemEventReceiver();
eventRecTemp.EnableEventFiring = false;
//update
eventRecTemp.EnableEventFiring = true;
```

or as [this](http://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/disable-item-events-firing-during-item-update/) blog talks about, turn it into a scope using `IDisposable`.

I used the scope method in an `ItemUpdated` heavy project and it worked well.